# Php alternative syntax highlighting

Tags: syntax, notepad++

Is there any way to get  tags and the if / endif stuff to highlight like the braces? Search brings me no help.

Answer (score 3):

I love that editor. Edit \plugins\APIs\php.xml to customize the syntax highlighting for PHP.